# unable to validate a field to show error message

Tags: validation, inputtext

I am unable to validate a field where if user enters a value in a text fields it must show error message data is not accepted

Comment: could you please elaborate the problem

Comment: I am having a text box where i will enter text and data should not be entered and it must show error message . I must use validation to do it

Comment: Didnt get the usecase. Just wondering of what is the need of having textbox when user shouldnt enter data..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following validation rule:- NOT( LEN( textfield_*c ) <= 0)  here textfield*_c is the field where you want to apply validation.